# Can we use same security group in launch configuration and classic load balancer?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am creating a (non default ) vpc and and associate a (non default) security group ( let say `sg-x`) with this vpc and set below inbound rules. outbound rules allowed all traffic.

[image: sg-x inbound rules]

in above picture **sg-dd3bdca1** is the peered vpc security group.

now create a classic load balancer (`lb-x`) with health check ping protocol is *tcp* and port is *22* and attach `sg-x` with this load balancer.

now create a launch configuration (`lc-x`) and attach the same security group `sg-x` with this launch configuration.

and than creating a auto scaling group (`asg-x`) which associate `lc-x` and attach `lb-x` and it's health check type is **EC2**.

My question is that Is this fine to add same security group in load balancer and launch configuration?

as far as it's working fine now but I am concerning for a valid answer for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My concern with this setup is lack of ability to open up ports and make changes to security groups in one part of the system without affecting other parts. For instance you might want to allow HTTPS from 0.0.0.0/0 to your ELB (if public service) but not to EC2 instances in the launch configuration as they might be non-public facing intended instances.

Comment: I want to open only TCP port. my one query is "What type of protocol used to access s3 bucket from ELB?"